# How to interpret coefficients of interaction terms in logistic regression in these 2 scenarios?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interaction, regression-coefficients

Let me give a simple example,

```
set.seed(100)
disease = sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE)
snp1 = sample(c("AA","AB","BB"),100,replace = TRUE)
snp2 = sample(c("XX","XY","YY"),100,replace = TRUE)

summary(glm(disease~snp1*snp2, family = binomial))
```

output1

```
Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.55176  -0.94003  -0.00649   0.90052   1.53535  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   -8.109e-01  6.009e-01  -1.349   0.1772  
snp1AB         5.232e-01  9.718e-01   0.538   0.5903  
snp1BB         1.504e+00  8.580e-01   1.753   0.0796 .
snp2XY         4.074e-16  8.498e-01   0.000   1.0000  
snp2YY         1.504e+00  9.280e-01   1.621   0.1051  
snp1AB:snp2XY  1.135e+00  1.335e+00   0.850   0.3952  
snp1BB:snp2XY  1.542e-01  1.254e+00   0.123   0.9022  
snp1AB:snp2YY -1.216e+00  1.333e+00  -0.912   0.3616  
snp1BB:snp2YY -2.785e+00  1.244e+00  -2.239   0.0252 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 138.63  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 127.71  on 91  degrees of freedom
AIC: 145.71
```

Output2

```
snp12 = interaction(snp1,snp2)
summary(glm(disease~snp12, family = binomial))


Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.55176  -0.94003  -0.00649   0.90052   1.53535  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -8.109e-01  6.009e-01  -1.349   0.1772  
snp12AB.XX   5.232e-01  9.718e-01   0.538   0.5903  
snp12BB.XX   1.504e+00  8.580e-01   1.753   0.0796 .
snp12AA.XY  -3.990e-16  8.498e-01   0.000   1.0000  
snp12AB.XY   1.658e+00  9.150e-01   1.812   0.0700 .
snp12BB.XY   1.658e+00  9.150e-01   1.812   0.0700 .
snp12AA.YY   1.504e+00  9.280e-01   1.621   0.1051  
snp12AB.YY   8.109e-01  8.333e-01   0.973   0.3305  
snp12BB.YY   2.231e-01  8.199e-01   0.272   0.7855  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 138.63  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 127.71  on 91  degrees of freedom
AIC: 145.71

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

So here I did a logistic regression for interaction between, lets say 2 mutations (each with 3 categories). Like shown above I can do it in 2 ways. My questions are,

1. Are both output1 and output2 same ?
2. If same, which one is more appropriate?
3. How to interpret the coefficients (and odds ratios) in each case?

Answer (score 2):

1 - Yes they are the same model parameterised differently

2 depends on which is easiest to interpret

3 - in the second case each of the eight cells is compared against the corner cell AA:XX. In the first case AB and BB are compared with AA (and similarly for XY, YY with XX) and then four extra terms tell you whether any of those cells needs an extra, so AB:XY is extra over and above what you would have expected from it being an AB and an XY. So for instance the predicted value for cell AB:XY is the intercept plus AB plus XY plus AB:XY

Comment: I didn't understand last part "then four extra ... and an XY". Can you please elaborate it ? Mainly I would like to know what each of the last four terms in output1 are compared to ? Thanks

Comment: Edited a bit extra explanation